# Pointer in function declaration

Tags: c++, function, pointers

i was anwsered a question about pointers lately on this forum. I was told that array is not a pointer(as it is common said) and it is good to know.
But i dont understand this thing now.

```
int function(int tab[]){..}..// normal declaration of function. i will put an addres of an array to this function

void function( int *tab[]){..; //but what does it mean? That i will send a pointer on the first element of the tab to the function?
```

I would be greateful if you could help me again!

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of an array of pointers?

Comment: Would it be more intuitive to you if I changed the whitespace to: `int* tab[]` instead of `int *tab[]`?

Comment: that means that tab[] is array of pointers who are pointing on int ?

Comment: okej, i checked it myself. It's exaclty what u said. TY a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
int tab[] == int * p // pointer to the first element of an array
int *tab[] == int ** p // pointer to the pointer to the first element of an array
```

Comment: Where does this const come from?

Comment: @lizusek tab[] - isn't technically array itself, instead it is permanent pointer to array, that permanently point to the first element of the array, it holds the address of tab[0]. Since it is permanent pointer - it's address can't be changed - hence const is used

Comment: this is not true. In C++, any function parameter of type "array of T" is adjusted to be "pointer to T"

Comment: @lizusek, thank you for the correction, I has looked through 4.2 of C++ 11, and has found that: "An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue
of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array" So I shall make adjustments accordingly to that information